# Problems running perl programe through R using system command

Tags: perl, r, system

when I run my perl programme using system I get the following error.

```
> system("perl txt2xlsx.pl", intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 2
Warning message:
running command 'perl txt2xlsx.pl' had status 2
```

However, when I run the script from terminal/console it works perfectly fine.
For testing purposes I put another perl script that just prints "Output" to the screen into the same directory and ran it with:

```
> system("perl test.pl",     intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
```

[1] "Output"

Works fine.

When you run my txt2xlsx.pl script without any arguments it prints:

```
Usage: txt2xlsx.pl <directory> <output file>
```

Can anyone imagine why R returns this error? It worked fine until I updated to the newest perl version:

```
This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for darwin-multi-2level
```

Cheers

Here is some of my perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# Check command line args
if($#ARGV != 1) {
     die("Usage: $0 <directory> <output file>\n\n");
}

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my $output = $ARGV[1];

print "Output    : $output\n";
print "Directory : $dir\n";

# Create excel workbook
my $wb = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($output);

# Process files
foreach (glob("$dir/*.txt")) {

....

}
#EOF
```

I did some more testing and reduced the perl script to print only the two arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# Check command line args
if($#ARGV != 1) {
     die("Usage: $0 <directory> <output file>\n\n");
}

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my $output = $ARGV[1];

print "Output    : $output\n";
print "Directory : $dir\n";
```

System works when I invoke the programme with its two expected arguments:

```
> system("perl test.pl asd dasd", intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
[1] "Output    : dasd" "Directory : asd"
```

without it produces the same error message:

```
> system("perl test.pl", intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 255
Warning message:
running command 'perl test.pl asd dasd' had status 255
```

I noticed when I comment `#use Excel::Writer::XLSX;` the system call using `system` fails with:

```
> system("perl test.pl asd dasd", intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 2
Warning message:
running command 'perl test.pl asd dasd' had status 2
```

So it looks like that it does not like the XLSX perl module. However, as I have already mentioned, running the script in the terminal works absolutely fine. And it also worked with the R system call before the update...

### --------------------

I am using StatET and Eclipse and i tried to run it in the normal R version. There the error message is much clearer. When I invoke a perl call through R, perl cannot find the XLSX package used in the code:

```
> system("perl test.pl asd asd", intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 2
Warning message:
running command 'perl test.pl asd asd' had status 2 
Can't locate Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin- 
thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-
2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 
/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.
```

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Can you provide the code for tst2xlsx.pl? Specifically, what does it exit with when you feed it no arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your perl script does in fact return an exit code of 2, which is a non-standard value meant to signal something.

Precisely because communicating via `system()` is so tedious, you could consider doing this in R itself.  If the source file is ascii, it is easy to read.  And packages [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/package=XLConnect) and [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xlsx) allow you to write in xlsx on any platform that R supports (and supports Java as as the xlsx read/write code comes from a Java jar file library).

Comment: Hey, I know all these R xlsx functions and we use them to read xlsx files into the system. However, our output files are so big that using xlxx function in R takes ages and in most cases fails with an error no one really knows how to fix it. I even contacted the developers but that did not lead to anything either... So I need to get this script running again.

Comment: xlsx has two interface, the more lightweight one is a lot faster. Did you try that?   But in any event: look at the Perl script and find why it returns 2.  That may signal an error condition too.

Comment: Well, the thing is as mentioned it works perfectly fine when I run it from the console. I cannot see why it should work differently by just calling it via system("perl txt2xlsx.pl"). So strange!

Comment: I do understand that it runs, but I asked you (twice now) to open the Perl in an editor and try to understand why/how it ends up exit code 2.

Comment: If your data is too big to effectively pipe to an xslx file, you could opt to drop Excel and use more appropriate tools. I realize this might not be possible given your circumstances, but using the wrong tool for the job can severely limit you. And Excel is one of the most misused tools...

Answer (score 0):

Your perl file **expects parameters on the command line**. It should be executed like this:

```
perl txt2xlsx.pl dir_to_outputfile outputfile.xls
```

Try changing your R file to

```
system("perl txt2xlsx.pl dir_to_outputfile output.xls", intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)
```

Comment: That's correct but before update what happened when you run it without any arguments system returned my defined 'die' string. I, of course, tried to run it with both arguments but same thing. It fails with above error message...

Comment: So if, from commandline, you run the `perl txt2xlsx.pl outputfile.xls` it works, but from R the `system("perl txt2xlsx.pl output.xls", intern=TRUE, wait=TRUE)` fails? Is perl receiving the argument? Can you modify test.pl to print `$#ARGV` and `$ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]`? Maybe R is "protecting" the system command from passing arguments?

Comment: I had a similar issue, but it went away if I did a `setwd("location of perl script")`, and then run the `system` command. Worth a shot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program in your terminal, you will have some environment variable set (like PERL5LIB) which is missing when run through R and is the one directing perl to find Excel::Writer::XLSX.

Run `env | grep PERL` to find out which

You could then export it, or pass the needed value to the -I parameter.